# Check checkbox state against original state in variable

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes with certain settings that I store in a variable on pageload. Now I want to check every change of them against the original state, so that I can do something if the original state is restored.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to check the states against the ones in the variable. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is what I got so far:

```
var ocs = $('.abocenter .subscriptions-lists input[type="checkbox"]');
$('.abocenter .subscriptions-lists').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    //Check against ocs somehow
});
```

The checkboxes have 4 different name types with mostly repeating values.

**SOLUTION**

I went for the simplest solution in my eyes. As a requirement I gave each check box element a data custom attribute, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="weekly" value="company" data-checked="true" checked>Company News
<input type="checkbox" name="weekly" value="structured" data-checked="false">Structured Finance
```

Now I just loop through each checkbox and compare the values with the current state:

```
$(".subscriptions-lists").on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var indicator = true;
    $(".subscriptions-lists input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
            if($(this).prop('checked') !== $(this).data('checked')) {
                indicator = false;
                //No more original state
            }
            if(indicator === false) {
                return;
            }
        }).promise().done( function() {
            if(indicator === true) {
                //Original State restored, do sth. :)
            }
        });
    });
```

Although I had some good answers to my question, I believe this is the best and simplest solution for me.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: can you show us how you stored the original state of the checkboxes?

Comment: I stored it in the variable `ocs` on document ready.

Comment: What kind of change you exactly want to check? do U mean whether they are checked or not??

Comment: @bhavya_w Yes. On page load some are checked, some are not. Then the user plays around, unchecking an checking some boxes (all without a submit). But if the original state of the page load of the checked and unchecked boxes is restored, I need to do a certain action.

Comment: @Sebsemillia : How does the original state of the page is restored? Does page state depends upon the whether different checkboxes are checked or not???

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ocs` to get the original states because it only contains references to the html elements. Then, when they change, the data you see in `ocs` changes too.

But if you want to know the default checked state, you can use

```
this.hasAttribute('checked')
```

Note this will only work if you changed their checked state in the proper way, that is, using `checked` property or jQuery's `prop()`. If you used `setAttribute()` or jQuery's `attr()`, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I didn't know that it contains only a reference which changes as well. Your idea with the checked attribute is good. I was also thinking about using a custom `data` attribute which shows the original state and then loop through the boxes and compare.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the elements have a "name", I'd personally do this-

```
var $subscriptionsLists = $('.abocenter').find('.subscriptions-lists'); // This is more efficient than a chained selector

var ocs = {}; // Plain JavaScript object

$subscriptionsLists.find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (index, checkbox) { // See http://api.jquery.com/each/ for details of the method
    ocs[checkbox.name] = checkbox.checked; // checkbox is a DOM element and not jQuery in each loop. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input
});

$subscriptionsLists.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (event) {
    if (ocs[this.name] !== this.checked) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

This could also be adapted to use ID if name is not available.

I have created a working [jsfiddle.net example](http://jsfiddle.net/oL28y3yx/) at http://jsfiddle.net/oL28y3yx/

Comment: Further this, you could store the state using the sessionStorage or localStorage APIs should the original state need to survive a page reload. If you are using a server side technology to set the values then this probably isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not implementable for me. Since it is in the nature of checkboxes to have repeating names for some of them it can't be the identifier and giving every box it's own id isn't a real solution as well.

Comment: @Sebsemillia If you want to compare the values individually you will need some way of individually retrieving and storing them - a key. This could be done via index of course, or a data-attribute value. Before I can modify the answer I will need a hint from you on how you in fact wish to implement it - it will waste both our time to keep guessing at specification. JavaScript variables can't start with a number so you'd have to combine indexes with some prefix string if you want to use those.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I worked out works by adding a custom data storage property to each checkbox so they all maintain their own state independently.

I added a JQuery extension method like so:

```
$.fn.IsOriginalState = function () {
    var data = $(this).prop("stateData");
    if (data == null || data == undefined) {
        data = {
            OriginalState: $(this).prop("checked"),
            CurrentState: $(this).prop("checked")
        }
        $(this).prop("stateData", data);
        data = $(this).prop("stateData");
    }
    return data.OriginalState == data.CurrentState;
};
```

Then, you can find out if an individual checkbox is in the original state by selecting it normally and invoking this function.

```
$("#checkbox1").IsOriginalState();
```

On page load, you then populate this by invoking the method on each checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        $(this).IsOriginalState(); //Set the initial values
    });
});
```

The final step is to setup a change event handler for each one to change the `CurrentState` property.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (data) {
    $(this).prop("stateData").CurrentState = $(this).prop("checked");
});
```

I have put together a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/1qmtkds9/

---

If you need an event to handle the condition when all checkboxes are in their original state (checked each time one is changed), I would create a custom event that is triggered each time a checkbox is changed that compares the checkbox states like this:

```
$(document).bind("check-changed", function (e) {
    var originalCount = 0;
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).IsOriginalState()) {
            originalCount++;
        }
    });
    var isOriginal = originalCount == $("input[type='checkbox']").length;
    if (isOriginal) {
        alert("Checkboxes are in their original state.");
    } // end if
});
```

Then make the change event behave this way:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (data) {
    $(this).prop("stateData").CurrentState = $(this).prop("checked");
    $(document).trigger("check-changed");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts! But unfortunately it is not doing what I need. Maybe you understood me wrong. Your solution gives me `true` when the original state of **one** checkbox is restored, but I need the `true` when the original state of **all** checkboxes is restored. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: The JSFiddle counts up the total number of checkboxes against the number of checkboxes in the original state to determine whether all are in the original state.  I will update my answer to include this detail.

Comment: @Sebsemillia Ah, so you want an event to be *triggered* when the initial state is restored.  I will update my answer to account for this.

Comment: Thank you for your update and all your efforts! But I went for a (in my eyes) less complicated solution. You can see it in my updated answer.